# Personal access token is not working for git command line

Tags: git, github

I created a new git repository for a project based on HTML-CSS-JS. When I am trying to push using git command line, I am getting this error.
I referred to these type of questions on stackoverflow, they are asking to set git personal access token and to enter the token code when git commandline is asking for password for authentication. 
But that is also not working for me.
Please guide

```
  remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
    remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
    fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/kartikdolas1997/pbvv-website.git/'
```

Comment: Can you please post the error you get when attempting to use a PAT instead of a password? The error you've posted is for when you attempt to use your password, yet you're saying using a PAT is not working.

Comment: If you attempt to enter a git token as the password then this is the error you will receive.

Answer (score -1):

When you simply want to push your new commits to Github you can also use SSH. That does not involve any tokens, only a SSH key. [Here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh) is the guide from Github on how to create an ssh key, add it to your Github Account and test the connection.